# Hyper-V and custom resolution

Tags: hyper-v, resolution

I know this question has been asked many times (here and on TechNet), and the answer is usually "use RDP". But apparently, RDP is now the only option, and it's what I'm using.

My screen is an LCD TV with a resolution of 1360x768. Unfortunately, this resolution is apparently not supported; the closest I can get in a Windows 8 VM is 1366x768, and it adds scrollbars, which make it difficult to put the mouse in the corners to get at the start screen and charm bar... Smaller resolutions don't fill the screen, so it's also difficult to put the mouse in the corner.

Is there a way to set a custom resolution to fit my screen exactly ?

(note: I know it's not a Windows 8 problem, since I don't have this problem on my host machine which also runs Windows 8. I assume it's related to the display adapter used by Hyper-V, but there don't seem to be any options to change it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try opening the RDP session at the command line, specifying exactly the resolution that you want:

`mstsc /v:WIN8_VM_HOSTNAME /w:1360 /h:768`

Another approach that should match the local desktop size exactly, assuming that the LCD TV is your only monitor on the client machine, is as follows:

`mstsc /v:WIN8_VM_HOSTNAME /span`

If you want the RDP session to launch in full screen mode, add `/f` to the end of the command.

Comment: It works, thanks! Actually I thought I was using mstsc because it looked exactly the same and the connection info mentioned Remote Desktop, but it was actually vmconnect.exe. With I don't even need to specify the resolution on the command line, it works fine with no arguments.

Comment: RDP via mstsc.exe will unfortunately not work if you have to use a VPN connection within the VM. The VPN stops all network connections and therefore a RDP connection fails. I do not understand why there is a limit of the screen resolution of the Hyper-V "Virtual Machine Connection" window. I would really appreciate fixing this limitation.